# Synchronizing Sky Force 2014 over two devices

Tags: android, sky-force-2014

I use [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en) on two different Android devices A and B. After using Sky Force 2014 on device A, how can I retrieve the progress on device B? I can connect to Facebook and Google if needed. I'd also be interested in synchronizing with my 3rd device, which runs on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the game for the first time on your second device, pass the initial demo play and the first real game play to enable the "High Scores" section's button. When its icon is enabled, press it, enter the high scores page and see the "Play Games" account icon at the bottom of it. Just press it and your account will be synchronized automatically. It takes a few restarts to fully synchronize all your progress (former purchases, extra planes etc) into the second device.

Comment: and if already installed on second device, clear data + (unsure if truly needed but in case) reinstall. Note that you might have to wait a few hours till device A's progress is synchronized with Sky Force server, which means that when connect your second device to Google, you might only retrieve the progress that you reached a few hours ago on device A.